# Angular 4 child route to always include param from parent

Tags: angular, angular4-router, angular-router-guards, angular-route-guards

I have an Angular 4 webapp, that currently hosts a multi tenant site.

An example url would be something like

```
www.example.com/tenant/
```

I have setup my routes as follows, to allow myself a 'tenant guard' ensuring I always have this property before attempting to render a route

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':tenant',
    canActivate: [TenantGuard, AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'protected',
        component: ProtectedComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

What I would like is to ensure that my router links always include the tenant.

Currently, my nav component looks something like

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
  <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['']">ng-webapp</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link"  [routerLink]="['']">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link"  [routerLink]="['protected']">Protected</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

However, clicking on 'protected' would in fact send me to

```
www.example.com/protected/
```

How I can setup any links on my child components to include the tenant param from the parent route?

```
www.example.com/tenant/protected/
```

One approach I considered was passing was passing the `ActivatedRoute` service from around my child components and constructing the urls within the component.

This seems a little inefficient though, is there another way to do this without including the router in every component?

Answer (score 0):

```
[routerLink]="['protected']"
```

Actually tells the router to look for the route in the current router-outlet.

So I imagine you aren't in the child outlet, but rather in the root one, right ?

If you want to redirect to protected, you have to do something like this :

```
[routerLink]="[userTenant, 'protected']"
```

Or, if your first tenant is set,

```
[routerLink]="['first-tenant', 'protected']"
```

Comment: How would my components know what userTenant is?

Comment: Because one way or the other, you set it. Otherwise, use the second solution, with a default tenant